# Not able to use Ok(...) for status code when returning an async'ed result in Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.2

I scaffolded a template for WebAPI looking like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ThingVm>>> GetThings()
{
  Task<List<ThingVm>> output = Context.Things
    .Select(e => new ThingVm(e))
    .ToListAsync();
  return await output;
}
```

I noticed that the returned result won't be communicating any status code (since I'm not providing either 200 or 404 etc.). So I added the standard, usual `Ok(...)` call.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ThingVm>>> GetThings()
{
  ...
  return await Ok(output);
}
```

Regrettably, the computer didn't appreciate that operation and explained the error like this.

> CS1061 'OkObjectResult' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'OkObjectResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I understand why it happens. What I don't know is how to resolve it **while retaining** the status code being emitted with the response.

I googled it but got hits on [insanely old stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11853812/1525840), [totally irrelevant stuff](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/52026396/ienumerable-entity---does-not-contain-a-definition-for--getawaiter--for-async-task-method) and [rather unrelated stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774931/listmyobject-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getawaiter). And that was it - not much other hits at all, which was surprising too.

How do I emit status code and apply the asynchronous approach? They aren't mutually exclusive, are they?

Comment: Have you tried to `output = await ...ToListAsync()` and then `return Ok(output);` ?

Comment: `Ok` isn't an asynchronous operation so ti makes no sense to use `await OK()`. It's no different than trying to call `await String.Join(...)`. The asynchronous operation is the one returned by `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Are you sure that your original solution doesn't return a 200?

Comment: @Fildor I have now. Didn't think of it. Still a bit worried there but I asked about that in the comment to the answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right, I see it now. I expected that each element being emitted up to the SPA receiving those would get a 200 with it. I see now that I confused myself here.

Comment: You can `return Ok(await output)`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Not sure if it does but I wouldn't be surprised if it did. However, in the actual ode, I might need to emit different status codes dependent on a bunch of weird conditions so I prefer to explicitly say to the receiver *this is OK* and *this is boo-boo*.

Comment: Well, it will, but your point is fair. In that case, there's no benefit to using `ActionResult<T>` - just use `IActionResult`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten that's comming in ASP.NET Core with IAsyncEnumerable<>. If you change the return type to `IAsyncEnumerable<>` instead of `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` you'll be able to stream the responses to the client

Comment: @KonradViltersten check [What's the big deal with IAsyncEnumerable<T> in .NET Core 3.0?](https://dev.to/dotnet/what-s-the-big-deal-with-iasyncenumerable-t-in-net-core-3-1eii)

Comment: @KirkLarkin I went with your suggestion and changed the signature to be simply `Task<IActionResult>` instead of the previous `Task<ActionResult<blabla>>`. Then, it got me thinking - is there anything to win on returning a task? It's an web based API emitting OK's with some junk in it or occassional Not-So-OK's with an error message. There's really no point tasking around there, is there? Everything will be performed synchronously up past the `Ok(...)` invokation...

Comment: It's still beneficial. Even with `return Ok(await output);`, the `await` will cause a continuation to be scheduled (assuming the task hasn't completed), which frees up the request-processing thread to take on another request while the `output` task continues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you not awaiting the result instead?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ThingVm>>> GetThings()
{
  var output = await Context.Things
    .Select(e => new ThingVm(e))
    .ToListAsync();

  return Ok(output);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `Ok` then

Comment: This certainly works. However, I was under the impression that the code provided here would lose it's asynchronicity as we're awaiting the result. Then, we're simply returning the whole shabang once it's been realized. Don't we?

Comment: @Fabio Could you explain why we're not needing `Ok()`? How does the receiver know what status code is emitted?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, action execution will be awaited anyway before proceeding to the next middleware layer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#specific-type)

Comment: @KonradViltersten As Fabio said, in both cases you are 'awaiting' the result. What are you expecting the `await Ok();` to do different than awaiting the result itself?

Comment: @RoelAbspoel Well, I **was** (note past tense) expecting to await each individual creation of  `ThingVm` and emitting it alongside with *200 OK*, one for each element. I was going to fetch those as they're produced in the observable service in the Angular app I have. I'm starting to realize that I need to approach it differently.

Comment: @KonradViltersten :) the `ToListAsync` will be awaited before the Ok is returned either way, so you will return the full collection when the entire call is executed.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Ok(...)  is synchronous and returns an `OkObjectResult` ([see source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/OkObjectResult.cs)). `Ok(...)` is just a wrapper around its constructor and constructors don't can't run async. You however can await the task inside the parameters though: `Ok(await Context.Things.Select(e => new ThingVm(e)).ToListAsync())`, but I wouldn't recommend that. Hard to debug, makes reading code harder too

Comment: Also just `await output` is bad, since when debugging you will see `Task<T>` and its properties in `output` variable, so its always better to await the operation then assign it (unless you are doing to start multiple tasks and want to await all or any of them)

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, it appears that the *actual* question is how to stream the results to the client. This isn't possible in ASP.NET Core 2.2. The asynchronous operation (`ToListAsync()`) has to complete first:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ThingVm>>> GetThings()
{
  Task<List<ThingVm>> output = Context.Things
    .Select(e => new ThingVm(e))
    .ToListAsync();
  return await output;
}
```

This changes in .NET Core 3 with the introduction of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. The article [What's the big deal with IAsyncEnumerable in .NET Core 3.0?](https://dev.to/dotnet/what-s-the-big-deal-with-iasyncenumerable-t-in-net-core-3-1eii) shows how an asynchronous action that returned all results at once

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProducts()
```

Can be converted to :

```
[HttpGet]
public IAsyncEnumerable<Product> Get()
    => productsRepository.GetAllProducts();
```

ASP.NET Core knows about `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and will write each result object to the output stream as it arrives.

EF Core 3 also supports IAsyncEnumerable, which means `GetThings()` can be changed to :

```
[HttpGet]
public IAsyncEnumerable<ThingVm> GetThings()
{
    var query = Context.Things
        .Select(e => new ThingVm(e))
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();
  return query;
}
```

[AsAsyncEnumerable](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/c2a39d700963f71c0035fa297aae6ec430578951/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2921) is nothing special, it just casts the query to an IAsyncEnumerable

A nice benefit of this is that our code no longer has to allocate a big list or array to hold the results before returning them

**Go Live**

.NET Core 3.0 Preview 7 has a [Go Live license and can be used in production](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-7/)