# C# Type T return with Func<T> delegate as argument

Tags: c#, types, delegates

I have this mapping function to convert types when migrating services to keep the return types compatible -

```
private T JsonMap<T>(object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
}
```

but what I find myself doing a lot is -

```
public async Task<T1> DoWork(T2 obj)
{
    var requestMapped = JsonMap<T3>(obj);
    var response = await _myService.DoWork(requestMapped);
    var responseMapped = JsonMap<T1>(response);
    return responseMapped;
}
```

As a result, I was trying to think of a way to incorporate that into the `JsonMap` function, but having difficulties there. Trying to have something like -

```
public async T1 JsonMap<T1>(object obj, Func<T3,T4> myFunc)
{
    var requestMapped = JsonMap<T3>(obj);
    var response = await myFunc(requestMapped);
    var responseMapped = JsonMap<T1>(response);
    return responseMapped;
}
```

and use it like this -

```
public async Task<T1> DoWork(T2 obj)
{
    return await JsonMap<T1>(obj, _myService.DoWork);
}
```

but I'm not too sure how that would work in terms of delegates. If someone could help point me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Comment: Start by looking at the errors that your code generates and solving each of those problems in turn.  A search on the error messages will provide plenty of useful information if you feel the messages are not adequately clear.

Comment: @Servy Well, trying that, but when adding the delegate to the parameter `JsonMap<T>(object obj, Func<T,T> myFunc)` How can I distinguish between the different types when I call the basic `JsonMap<T>` function?

Comment: Exactly the way you did in the code in your question, use different types for each of the places you need different types.

Comment: @Servy Oooh, I think I need to add all the types to `JsonMap<T1, T2, T3>....` got it

Comment: @Servy now getting a `T3` does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter... not sure how to resolve that one

Comment: Like I said, if you don't understand a given error message, search for it, and you'll find lots of helpful information.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774931/listmyobject-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getawaiter/40839752

Comment: @Servy thanks! cheers

Comment: I think you might need to show more code / detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use declared delegates and pass them to your generic process.
I have updated the example to make it async, at the end of the day you should be able to call

```
Converter c = new Converter();
TestType2 tt2 = new TestType2() { testValue = "Something to test" };
TestType1 tt1 = await c.JsonMap<TestType1, TestType2>(tt2);
```

I have put an example as [RexTester](https://rextester.com/BZAQ4950)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class TestType1
    {
        public string testValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestType2
    {
        public string testValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestType3
    {
        public string testValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Conversion
    {
        public System.Type ConverionType { get; set; }
        public object ConversionFunction { get; set; }
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public delegate Task<T> processingFuncDel<T, T1>(T1 value);
        Dictionary<System.Type, Conversion> conversionDelegates = new Dictionary<System.Type, Conversion>();

        public Converter()
        {
            processingFuncDel<TestType2, TestType3> convert3To2 = new processingFuncDel<TestType2, TestType3>(myFunc);
            Conversion c = new Conversion() { ConverionType = typeof(TestType3), ConversionFunction = convert3To2 };
            conversionDelegates.Add(typeof(TestType3), c);

            // Add more converters here
        }

        public async Task<T1> JsonMap<T1, T2>(T2 obj)
        {
            if (conversionDelegates.ContainsKey(obj.GetType()))
            {
                System.Type ct = conversionDelegates[obj.GetType()].ConverionType;
                if(ct == typeof(TestType3))
                {
                    return await JsonMap<T1, T2, TestType3>(obj, (processingFuncDel<T2, TestType3>)conversionDelegates[obj.GetType()].ConversionFunction);
                }
                // Add more cases here, or use reflection to try an do it dynamically...
            }
            return default(T1);
        }

        public async Task<T1> JsonMap<T1, T2, T3>(T2 obj, processingFuncDel<T2, T3> myFunc)
        {
            T3 requestMapped = JsonMap<T3>(obj);
            T2 response = await myFunc(requestMapped);
            T1 responseMapped = JsonMap<T1>(response);
            return responseMapped;
        }

        public T JsonMap<T>(object obj)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
        }

        public async Task<TestType2> myFunc(TestType3 obj)
        {
            // Do your async processing here, this is just an example
            TestType2 ret = new TestType2() { testValue = obj.testValue };
            return ret;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Converter c = new Converter();
            TestType2 tt2 = new TestType2() { testValue = "Something to test" };
            // Make an async call to convert
            TestType1 tt1 = c.JsonMap<TestType1, TestType2>(tt2).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Asynchronous delegates](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) are just like regular delegates, except the return type is wrapped in `Task<>`. So in your case, you'd want something like `Func<T1, Task<T2>>`:

```
public async Task<T1> JsonMap<T1, T3, T4>(object obj, Func<T3, Task<T4>> myFunc)
{
    var requestMapped = JsonMap<T3>(obj);
    var response = await myFunc(requestMapped);
    var responseMapped = JsonMap<T1>(response);
    return responseMapped;
}
```

The problem with very-generic methods like this is that the consumer has to specify all the type parameters explicitly. C# doesn't allow you to specify only the first parameter and infer the other two:

```
_ = await JsonMap<T1, T3, T4>(obj, _myService.DoWork);
```

You can work around this with a few type tricks, e.g.:

```
public static class JsonMapper<T1>
{
  public static async Task<T1> Map<T3, T4>(object obj, Func<T3, Task<T4>> myFunc)
  {
    var requestMapped = JsonMap<T3>(obj);
    var response = await myFunc(requestMapped);
    var responseMapped = JsonMap<T1>(response);
    return responseMapped;
  }
}
```

which can be used as:

```
_ = await JsonMapper<T1>.Map(obj, _myService.DoWork);
```

Alternatively, you can drop the final mapping from your implementation:

```
public async Task<T4> JsonMap<T3, T4>(object obj, Func<T3, Task<T4>> myFunc)
{
    var requestMapped = JsonMap<T3>(obj);
    var response = await myFunc(requestMapped);
    return response;
}
```

which can be used as:

```
_ = await JsonMap<T1>(JsonMap(obj, _myService.DoWork));
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't answer your question exactly, but you might be able to reach your goal of simpler code simply by changing `JsonMap` to an extension method.

```
static public T JsonMap<T>(this object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
}
```

Now `DoWork` is one line:

```
public Task<T1> DoWork(T2 obj)
{
    return _myService.DoWork(obj.JsonMap<T3>()).JsonMap<T1>;
}
```